# Pyodbc DataError 22003 when selecting data from NAV database

Tags: python, sql, excel, pyodbc, dynamics-nav

I am using Pyodbc to select data from my company's Dynamics NAV database and it has been working great so far using the select string created by Excel / microsoft query, but now I want to use the WHERE clause to only select information from a specific vendor. The vendor NO is their a number stored as a string in the column"Buy-from Vendor No_" and when I try to use this I run into a problem with the SQL query. A simplified version of the statement looks like this:

```
'SELECT "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line"."Planned Receipt Date", "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line"."Vendor Item NO_", "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line".No_ FROM COMPANYDB.dbo."Companyname A_S$Purchase Line" "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line" WHERE ("Companyname A_S$Purchase Line"."Buy-from Vendor No_"="96100961") ORDER BY "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line"."Order Date" DESC'
```

This results in the following error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name '96100961'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

If i replace the number string with a %s and insert the number using single quotes I get an error about converting varchar to int because one of the vendor NO's is higher than the int limit.

If I try to use the where clause on a INT data column it works, so I guess there is a issue with the quotes or double quotes?

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
'SELECT "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line"."Planned Receipt Date", "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line"."Vendor Item NO_", "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line".No_ FROM COMPANYDB.dbo."Companyname A_S$Purchase Line" "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line" WHERE ("Companyname A_S$Purchase Line"."Buy-from Vendor No_"='+"'96100961'"+') ORDER BY "Companyname A_S$Purchase Line"."Order Date" DESC'
```

Sometimes I just need to think for a moment.